# Progressive rendering parallel coordinate d3.js V4 with reorderable axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am referring to this base code for progressive rendering parallel coordinates https://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/482706e0638c67836d94b20f0cb37122

Can we have reorderable axis in this, that is I am looking to drag and reorder the axis.

The code to reorder axis in another parallel coordinate(this one is without progressive rendering) is given here https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281

So, I am looking forward to merge reorderable axis feature in the progressive rendering parallel coordinate.
Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with `progressive rendering` and with `reorder axis`. To me both examples do the same thing with only a different dataset. I am not able to change the order of the axis in the second example or at least it is not intuitive or described. If you mean brushing the axis it is possible in both. Now I found the reordering by hovering over the axis labels.

Comment: In progressive rendering, the parallel coordinates are generated in a canvas by using render function. But in the second example it is generated using simple svg path. Also in the second example, If you drag the axis labels, you can reorder/shuffle the axis. I am looking for similar reorder behaviour in the first example. Please comment if you have any further doubts regarding question.

Comment: it all comes do to how many rows of data you have. If you have about as many as the planets the canvas way is the easy method because then you can interrupt the update with new sub-data-set. Also the planets example does not want to construct a custom line path with holes. First port example 2 to d3v4 or d3v5. In the cars example the `dimensions` are constructed on the fly based on CSV columns, with planets they are hardcoded. Make sure you do not allow to drag the first and last column, they have different with.

Comment: yes, actually I have many data points and thats why I am using the canvas way. It uses render_queue to plot the lines. I am looking to add the reorder feature    ( you can see the lines 87-116 in the second example ) to this canvas plot. I have already ported the example in d3v4, this is just for the reference.